# Buttons are not working in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, button

I'm having an issue with a website I've created for a school assignment. As the title says, buttons don't seem to be working in Google Chrome or Firefox. I got it working in IE (the horror), where I have to Allow "Blocked Content." The problem is, I don't know what "blocked content" is referred to..

```
<button href="#" onclick="switchImage('slideImg')">
Play
</button>
```

Here I'm using Javascript, but buttons in general don't actually work, for example:

```
<button>
Click me!
</button>
```

doesn't show the visual for clicking a button.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you show all your code? E.g. JavaScript?

Comment: href attribute is not for button, they are for image and linkbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function switchImage(str)
{
 alert(str);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="switchImage('slideImg')">Play</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working. You can verify it from http://fiddle.jshell.net/Jd2yP/15/

Comment: That worked, there was an error in my JS, so I had to rewrite a few lines of that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add [*the mark of the web*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX) immediately after your Doctype to tell IE to run the page in the Internet security zone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```